# My code has an if-else condition but i think the code is not checking the if condition instead going straight to else condition

Tags: python

I have this code to change the filesystem size. The problem is that even though the if condition is satisfied it is not going into if condition and i do not have if it is checking the if condition at all. It is straight forwardly going to the else condition.

## **The result after running the code**

> post-install-ray.py chpasswd
>
> chpasswd root:Deepsky24
>
> df -g | grep -w / | awk '{ print $3 }'
>   0.89
>
> df -g | grep -w /usr | awk '{print $3 }'
>   5.81
>
> chfs -a size=+4G / Filesystem size changed to 10354688

Code :

```
import subprocess
import sys
import pexpect
from pexpect import pxssh
import logging

password = "Deepsky24"
hostname = "host"
username = "root"

def change_filesystem():
    child = pxssh.pxssh()
    child.login(hostname, username, password)
    child.sendline("df -g | grep -w / | awk '{ print $3 }'")
    child.prompt()
    output1 = child.before
    print output1
    child.sendline("df -g | grep -w /usr | awk '{print $3 }'")
    child.prompt()
    output2 = child.before
    print output2
    if (output1 <= 1 and output2 >= 4):

        child.sendline('chfs -a size=-3G /usr')
        child.prompt()
        print(child.before)
        child.sendline('chfs -a size=+3G /')
        child.prompt()
        print(child.before)

    else:

        child.sendline('chfs -a size=+4G /')
        child.prompt()
        print(child.before)

if __name__== "__main__":

        change_filesystem()
```

Comment: What does `output1` and `output2` prints?

Comment: What @AvihooMamka said. I'm fairly confident the `if-else` bit is working correctly. Hence the problem must be that `output1` and `output2` must be other than what you think they are.

Comment: The two output values are shown above the code snippet - 0.89 and 5.81

Comment: So they are. Silly me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your are on python 2.

`child.before` return a string.
you comparing a string to integer and getting unexpected results.
cast your outputs with `int()` or `float()`

with python 3 you whould have got an exception

Answer (score 2):

Your two outputs are still strings, you need to convert them to floats

```
output1 = float(child.before)
output2 = float(child.before)
```